# Operator+ and -in complex class C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how the non member functions operator+ and operator- works in the complex class in C++.

cppreference states:

"Implements the analogs of the unary arithmetic operators for complex numbers.

1) Returns the value of its argument

2) Negates the argument

Return Value:

1) a copy of the argument, std::complex(val)

2) negated argument, std::complex(-val.real(), -val.imag())"

For what i understand it only returns the real and imag values of the complex number? Thats just an getter function then, it actually dont do any adding or subtraction?
I cant access the real and imag values inside the class as this is not a member function, i just dont get how this one is implemented and used?

Anyone that could explain this for me? I have tried searching on google but couldnt find anything.
Thanks in advance, maybe i am stupid for not understanding this one.

Comment: You're probably looking at the _unary_ (one-argument) `+` and `-` operators, but more interested in the _binary_ operators.

Comment: You are looking at the unary operator reference, not the [binary operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) reference.

Comment: yes i am, i am supposed to implement the unary operators for school but i cant understand how or get what they are used for.

Comment: its the same as with numbers: +1 is using the unary + and -1 is using the unary -. Or if you have eg -1 then the unary minus will give you -(-1) = 1. As you already realized, the unary + is just the identity, but still you have to implement it, otherwise you could not write something like `complex y = +x;` (or `complex y = -x;` requires a definition of a unary - operator)

Comment: _"...but i cant understand how or get what they are used for..."_: Even though `+1` does not change the value of `1` it still applies the `operator+` (unary plus) to the value `1`.

Comment: @liljan Doesn't look like you do, since you have a "_it actually dont do any adding or subtraction_" wording in your post. I think you might be confused as to what unary and binary operators represent. And I don't think you should inherit from the `std::complex` class template.

Comment: The two items under "Return Value" literally show you how you can implement them.

Comment: Ok if i understand it correctly, if + it should just return the value and if - i should just negate the value?